# Is it there a way to find an specific color percentage of an Image Using OpenCv with python?

Tags: python, pixel, opencv

I need to know how much black is inside an image to determine if a checkbox is filled or isn't.

That's the code I have found but i doesn't work for me for any color:

```
pathImagen = 'fichaje2AnalizarRedimensionado.png' 
img= cv2.imread(pathImagen)

brown = [0, 0, 0]  # RGB
diff = 20
boundaries = [([brown[2]-diff, brown[1]-diff, brown[0]-diff],
               [brown[2]+diff, brown[1]+diff, brown[0]+diff])]
# in order BGR as opencv represents images as numpy arrays in reverse order

for (lower, upper) in boundaries:
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype=np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype=np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    ratio_brown = cv2.countNonZero(mask)/(img.size/3)
    print('brown pixel percentage:', np.round(ratio_brown*100, 2))

    cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Initially this code was for brown color but I need to check the black color so that's the reason I changed it to [0,0,0]

Do you know how to determine from an image the black color (or the white color) percentage?

Comment: Please provide your input image.

Comment: Why do you  need the images?